Should HVAC have cleanout tee near the trap drain?
My 5yo 4.5 ton variable Bosch air handler is sweating a bit, in my spray foam attic that is averaging 80° and 65% humidity.  I've recently washed the coils outside, tried to vacuum the condensate PVC pipe from the outside, but there's still 1/8th inch of water in the safety pan where it's sweating upstairs.
Is it not a good idea to add a clean out tea after the P-trap? The three-quarter inch PVC drain does a couple 90° turns and heads straight down my wall cavity into the crawlspace where there's another 90° bend draining it right outside in my backyard. It's a steady trickle of water. Link to video of the setup

(A pic or video is worth a thousand words.)
Now seeing the video, I would guess that there is some blockage in or to the drain inside the air-handler. That much water is more than some sweating.
A clean out before the first elbow outside the unit would make cleaning in both directions easier.

The drip pan has its own 3/4" PVC drain independent of the primary. It basically runs parallel.  It's nice because I can drain a dehumidifier down the secondary.  I"m not sure if a clean out T should go before p-trap right near the air handler, or after it.....or perhaps right where the 90 goes from horizontal (sloped) to vertical down into my wall cavity. I'd like to vacuum  out the p-trap but also want to be able to pour vinegar down to clean it.

I'm mainly talking theory here. Without a pic to see what you are seeing it's difficult for me to picture in my mind what setup you have.  I would do whatever is easiest for me to reach my goals and not cause an issue with drainage.

I thought I added a link to a YouTube video that I posted to help me, by making it clear for anyone willing to take a look at it, here it is: https://youtu.be/jNBIDVUoWes?si=tqRrpr0ek9pmU7BJ

I edited the description to make it noticable.

Yes you should have a cleanout where you say you should.  A good way to add one would be to buy a new better P trap.  Transparent for inspection and with cleanout caps on both sides of it.

Also, the way you hooked up your dehumidifier, if the secondary line gets blocked further down, the dehumidifier condensate will back up into the Air Conditioner secondary pan.  You have a sensor there that will shut down your A/C but it won't shut down the dehumidifier.  You could rig that up with that sensor or with a new IoT sensor and smart switch.
